# Cake hp model validation message not showing in HTML form

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this simple user model which validates the field if it is empty and should give the message, but it is not picking up model message instead giving HTML message.This is the code for my model validation

```
public $validate = array(
        'first_name' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'This field cannot be empty',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
```

Test link: http://59655b15.ngrok.com/medicare/users/home

Click on signup tab and click create profile button in the popup without entering any first name. It should show the message of model but it is showing default message. If I remove the validation from model it does not do any validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you're seeing is the standard browser message that appears when a field has the 'required' attribute, but has no content in it.

You're not seeing the Model's message because at that point, it hasn't even submitted yet.

Assuming you use the FormHelper, CakePHP automatically adds the 'required' attribute on fields that cannot be empty.

[Example of the required field in action with it's HTML](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mattc/2008/10/26/automagic-javascript-validation-helper).

---

If you want really want to have your model messages as the Javascript validation, you could look into building it out or at some of the exisitng helpers/plugins...etc.

An example (albeit a bit old):  [Automagic Javascript Validation Helper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mattc/2008/10/26/automagic-javascript-validation-helper)

Comment: Hi, I am new to cakephp, I have a doubt, I am trying to call ajax for the validation in my sign up form. My ajax is not returning any data. Is this because of the same problem?? Will Ajax return every validation made for that id in model?? Can you please help out with the code to use model validation in javascript. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you'd like help with your ajax code, please create a new question with the details of your problem.  (You didn't mention ajax even once in your question.)  This one has been answered and is correct.  As you can see by the Network tab of any Developer Toolkit, hitting submit on your form does NOT run your ajax code.